# service worker register , my code is below console show empty and service worker is not show anything

Tags: json, push-notification, service-worker

// my path file is also checked
if('serviceworker' in navigator){

```
 navigator.serviceworker
 .register('serviceworker.js')
 .then((reg)=>console.log('serviceworker registered',reg))
 .catch((err)=>console.log('service worker not registered',err));
```

}